# Problem extracting elements inside html <script> using BeautifulSoup in python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, scrape

I want to scrape Product Information from Div below, but when I prettify the HTML I am not able to find the main DIV in HTML.

```
<div class="c2p6A5" data-qa-locator="product-item" data-tracking="product-card"
```

The elements I am trying to fetch is in the following script. I need to know how can I extract data from Script below:

```
<script type="application/ld+json"></script>
```

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.57446b5079XMO8"
page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `.find()` or `find_all()`

when I do that, I see it's actually in json format, so then can just read that element and have all the data stored that way.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

url = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=dell&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.searchlist.search.go.57446b5079XMO8"
page = requests.get(url)

print(page.status_code)
print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())



alpha = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)

for item in jsonObj['itemListElement']:
    name = item['name']
    price = item['offers']['price']
    currency = item['offers']['priceCurrency']
    availability = item['offers']['availability'].split('/')[-1]
    availability = [s for s in re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", availability) if s]
    availability = ' '.join(availability)

    url = item['url']

    print('Availability: %s  Price: %0.2f %s   Name: %s' %(availability,float(price), currency,name))
```

**Output:**

```
Availability: In Stock  Price: 82199.00 Rs.    Name: DELL INSPIRON 15 5570 - 15.6"HD - CI5 - 8THGEN - 4GB - 1TB HDD -  AMD RADEON 530 2GB GDDR5.
Availability: In Stock  Price: 94599.00 Rs.    Name: DELL INSPIRON 15 3576 - 15.6"HD - CI7 - 8THGEN - 4GB - 1TB HRD - AMD Radeon 520 with 2GB GDDR5.
Availability: In Stock  Price: 106399.00 Rs.    Name: DELL INSPIRON 15 5570 - 15.6"HD - CI7 - 8THGEN - 8GB - 2TB HRD -  AMD RADEON 530 2GB GDDR5.
Availability: In Stock  Price: 17000.00 Rs.    Name: Dell Latitude E6420 14-inch Notebook 2.50 GHz Intel Core i5 4GB 320GB Laptop
Availability: In Stock  Price: 20999.00 Rs.    Name: Dell Core i5 6410 8GB Ram Wi-Fi Windows 10 Installed ( Refurb )
Availability: In Stock  Price: 18500.00 Rs.    Name: Core i-5 Laptop Dell 4GB Ram 15.6 " Display Windows 10 DVD+Rw ( Refurb )
Availability: In Stock  Price: 8500.00 Rs.    Name: Laptop Dell D620 Core 2 Duo 80_2Gb (Used)
...
```

EDIT: To see the difference in the 2 json structures:

```
jsonObj_0 = json.loads(alpha[0].text)
jsonObj_1 = json.loads(alpha[1].text)

print(json.dumps(jsonObj_0, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print(json.dumps(jsonObj_1, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: thanks. now I am able to find my desired products with your suggested code.Cheers

Comment: Why don't we use [0]  in jsonObj instead of [1]? jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)

Comment: you could, but there's no relevant data that you want in there in terms of the products. if you print out each `print (alpha[0])` and print (alpha[1])` you can see the difference

Comment: Yes got it now, Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to fetch all URL's from json. I am only getting one product URL. Code is mentioned below: 

alpha = soup.find_all('script',{'type':'application/ld+json'})
jsonObj = json.loads(alpha[1].text)
for url in jsonObj['itemListElement']:
    name = item['url']

Comment: `for url in jsonObj['itemListElement']: name = item['url']` should be `for item in jsonObj['itemListElement']: url_name = item['url']`

Comment: @chittown88. I tried this too but only showing 1 result. I want all the product URL's

Comment: check the edit above. I'm not sure what you mean by it's only showing 1 result. Where is it only showing 1 results?